# Does every generic in Rust have to implement some trait in order to have 'methods'?

Tags: rust

I don't have control over `A` and `B` below, they come from a library. Both implement the `hello` method, and I'd like to create a function that acts on both, but I don't want to reuse code. On C++, it does not check if a template parameter implements any methods, it just checks if the type in the instantiation implements the method. Take a look:

```rust
pub struct A {
    x: u8,
}

impl A {
    pub fn new() -> A {
        A { x: 0 }
    }
    pub fn hello() {
        println!("hello")
    }
}

pub struct B {
    x: u8,
}

impl B {
    pub fn new() -> B {
        B { x: 1 }
    }
    pub fn hello() {
        println!("hello")
    }
}

pub fn say_hello<T>() {
    let t: T = T::new();
    t.hello();
}

fn main() {
    say_hello::<A>();
    say_hello::<B>();
}
```

This wont compile because it says `T` does not have the `say_hello` method. Since this is from a library, I cannot implement a trait for them. So there's nothing I can do here? I'll have to duplicate code?

Note that it can be known at compile time if both the intantiation types `A` and `B` have the `hello` method. C++ wouldn't care.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLDR: yes.

C++'s templates are indeed differ from generic types (particularly in Rust). The first one works by substitution without digging into the type at time of item definition, but only **at time of use**. So in C++, I believe, it is possible to create a templated item that at the same time compiles and cannot have an instantiation because of conflicting requirements.

This is not the case for generic types in Rust, these are checked while you define a generic item, e.g. `T` in `fn f<T>(..) {..}`. So the compiler analyzes all of the usages of the type `T` and its instances so these are used properly.

So in general yes, you need to have a trait bound to use types' methods. As for your case this might be a preferred solution:

```rust
trait Hello {
    fn say_hello();
}

impl Hello for A {
    fn say_hello() {
        A::hello()
    }
}

impl Hello for B {
    fn say_hello() {
        B::hello()
    }
}
```

If you'd like to have a behavior similar to templates in C++ you may take a look at [macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-06-macros.html):

```rust
macro_rules! say_hello {
    ($t:ty) => {{
        <$t>::hello()
    }}
}

fn main() {
    say_hello!(A);
    say_hello!(B);
}
```

Comment: I’d mention that one can create a trait and implement it on foreign types before the macro solution.

Comment: Probably it was too briefly discussed indeed. Extended with an example, thanks